# Descargar imagen HTML

Tags: html

Tengo este codigo:

```
<td class=suplantacion><div align="center">Nombre_Tabla</div><a href=<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%> 
    download=<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%>>Imagen</a></td>
```

El cual al dar un click en el link se muestra una imagen, estoy utilizando el atributo download pero, solo me muestra la imagen y necesito que la descrague

Comment: <a download="mi-imagen.jpg" href="/url/hacia/imagen" title="nombreImagen">
    <img alt="nombreImagen" src="/url/hacia/imagen">
</a>.......puedes usar este metodo

Comment: ¿Cuál es la URL de la imagen y la URL de la página? ¿Están en el mismo dominio/origen?

Comment: Para que se descargue una imagen debes estar en un servidor ya sea local o en una página. Si no tienes ningún servidor solo te mostrará la imagen

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funcionó pero realmente para que funcione necesitas un servidor local o si no el download no funciona

Answer (score -1):

No agregues a **download** atributo alguno:

```
<a href="<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%" download>Imagen</a>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no poner valor al atributo `download` solucionaría el problema? Según [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) debería funcionar igualmente con o sin valor.